# NetLogo chain of turtles breaks up when linking

Tags: netlogo

I'm doing a model of some chains of cells (as part of a larger DNA string model). They wiggle around on screen, and when they wiggle so much, that they come close to a cell of the same type in the same string, they must create a link with that cell.

Code below.

It kinda works.... But after I introduced the linking behavior described above, the string breaks into pieces after a short while. I can't figure out why :-) Any ideas?

Thanks,

Palle

```
breed [cells cell]
cells-own [paired?]

globals [chains]

to setup
  clear-all
  set chains []
  addchain
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  foreach chains [c -> movechain c]

  ask cells [if any? other cells-here with [label = [label] of myself and paired? = false] [
    let makker one-of other cells-here with [label = [label] of myself and paired? = false]
    create-link-with makker [tie]
    set color red
    set paired? true
    ask makker [set color red set paired? true]
    print word label " was found!"
  ]]

  tick
end

to addchain
  set chains lput makechain chains
end

to movechain [mylist]

  let antalfollowers length mylist - 1

  let i antalfollowers
  repeat antalfollowers [
    ask item i mylist [
      move-to (item (i - 1) mylist)
    ]
    set i i - 1
  ]

   ask first mylist [
    right random-float wigglefactor
    left random-float wigglefactor
    fd 1
  ]

end

to-report makechain
  let mylist []
  let text "MGIVEQCCTSICSRYQ"
  let startx random-xcor / -3
  let starty random-ycor / -3

  let i 0
  repeat length text [
    create-cells 1 [
      set color green
      set shape "circle"
      set label item i text
      set paired? false
      set mylist lput self mylist
      setxy startx + i * .75 starty + i * .75
    ]
    set i i + 1
  ]

  report mylist
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - I finally figured out what's going on. This was hard to see. The tricks I used
in order to see it are listed at the bottom of this post.

**In the case of a single strand** of synthetic DNA floating around,
when two cells of the same type hit and stick, at that point there will 
be a loop of all the cells that were **between** the moving cell and the
cell that got run into in the list of the sequence of cells.

What you need to do is to:

(a) take the cell that just got run into and link it and tie it to the moving 
     cell,  making the moving cell the MASTER of the link [tie]. You do that
     already.

(b) remove the cell you just made a SLAVE from the list of cells your code 
    has to move, because it will now be moved automatically when the master cell
    moves.

AND ... importantly ...

(c)  repeat steps (a) and (b) for EVERY cell on the list in positions between
     the two cells that just collided and stuck.**

That will effectively freeze the configuration of the entire loop and make it 
into a single large unit that will move as one unit when the master cell is 
moved by your code.

The User Manual states in the subsection on TIE in the section on LINKS:

> When the root turtle turns right or left, the leaf turtle rotates
>   around the root turtle the same amount as if a stiff were attaching
>   the turtles. When tie-mode is set to “fixed” the heading of the leaf
>   turtle changes by the same amount.

I think that you do want to set tie-mode to FIXED so the whole cluster will rotate when the master cell rotates.

I think, but have not looked at it, that this algorithm will work even if the linked cell is the very first or very last one on the chain.  Better check it though. Maybe the cell that should be the MASTER is the one that got hit, not the one doing the moving.

**In the case of two different strands of DNA intersecting**, 
basically forming an X, or more complicated cases ... I leave it up to you to figure out what you want the larger connected structure to do, and how hit should move.   Do BOTH of the leading cells of each strand tug on it at once? Do you need to shut off one of them so there is only  one cell moving the crowd?   Will you need to change your code that moves the chain to insert one of the chains entirely into the middle of the other chain on the list that moves them in sequence?  I don't know!

**By the way, to figure this out, I had to:**

- slow down the motion and
- set the color of the cells to [0 255 0 125] which is a half-transparent green 
  so I could see through them and see through them overlap, and
- use the "watch" feature of the Inspector to follow one of the cells I knew
  was going to get linked up, and
- use the slider in the inspector to zoom up as far as it would go, and
- put a 500 millisecond "wait" in side the innermost loop of the motion.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks! I'll try it out, but I think I'll also try out an alternative with dx/dy calculations of speeds - similar to the Rope model in the Model Library - but in two dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on your question and have made some progress -- at least I have a revision of your code with some troubleshooting additions to it, and a revision of the Interface.  I can't figure out how to attach a model here, or an image of the view you will see when you run it, so I posted the full model and a PNG file in the [netlogo-users Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!newtopic/netlogo-users).

The revisions do not fully answer your question about how to solve the breaking up of the chain, but they provide a reproducible version of the model that you can be sure will break at step 746 and that you can turn on dense printing and slow action and watch what is going on with attempted moves after that.

Maybe if we both look at that it will be obvious why this is breaking.

One thing I think may be happening is that, once two cells link and tie, your move algorithm no longer is the correct logic for how the knotted chain should move.

Here's the changes that I made:

- I added a random-seed command in setup so that the model can be repeatedly run with exactly the same choices in random variables, so we can both look at the results.
- I added a "verbose?" switch on the Interface to turn on or off detailed printing of what's going on.
- I added a "clear-stop" button that will allow the "stop" commands I put in the model to stop the running using a stop-requested? flag, which the code sets and this button resets so that "go" and "one step" work again after a stop and the ticks counter keeps on incrementing.
- I added a msec-per-tick slider to put a fixed number of milliseconds at the end of the go step so the model will run at a speed that is usable for debugging.  I don't know how other people can do it -- when I try to use the built-in slider at the top of the interface to control speed, either it's way too slow, or it's way too fast, and I can't seem to be able to tweak it to just right.  So I added this kludge.
- I guessed what limits you had on your wigglefactor slider on your interface and made one that goes from 0 to 90 (degrees).  It works ok and reproduces your bug.
- **I added some additional tests to prevent the two C-cells that are adjacent in your choice of cells from linking to each other when they discover, as they do sometimes, that they are on the same patch.**  With a random seed of 23456   your original code ties its own CC adjacent pair together in tick 2 for instance.

(

Here's the revised code, and comments as to how to use it are in the posted model (in netlogo-users) and below after the code as well.

```
breed [cells cell]
cells-own [paired?]

globals [
  chains
  stop-requested?  ;;//////////////////////////////////////////////////
]

to setup
  clear-all
 ;; random-seed 12345  ;; /////////////// breaks at either step 35 or 45  ////
 ;; random-seed 23456 ;; ////////////////// ties its own CC in tick 2 ///
  random-seed 34567 ;; /////////////////// ties own cc in tick 84 ,  ties C at 746 and breaks in 6 steps
  ;;// wow -- it SNIPS TSIC out of the middle of the chain!!  snips out CTIS, turtles 7 8 9 and 10
  ;; cell 6 C  is directly followed by cell 11  -- also C




  set chains []
  addchain
  set stop-requested? FALSE ;; ////////////////////////////////////////
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  if stop-requested? [ stop ] ;;////////////////////////////////////////////
  foreach chains [c -> movechain c]
  ask cells [if any? other cells-here with [label = [label] of myself and paired? = false
    and who != [who] of myself + 1
    and who != [who] of myself - 1

  ] [
    let makker one-of other cells-here with [label = [label] of myself and paired? = false]
    create-link-with makker [tie]
    set color red
    set paired? true
    ask makker [set color red set paired? true]
    print ( word label " was found at tick " ticks)
    set stop-requested? TRUE ;;/////////////////////////////////////////////
  ]]


   wait ( msec-per-tick / 1000 ) ;;////////////////////////////////////////
  tick
end

to addchain
  set chains lput makechain chains
end

to movechain [mylist]

  if verbose? [print ( word "\n\nin code at tick " ticks " starting movechain") ];;//////////////
  ;;if verbose? [ show mylist ]

  let antalfollowers length mylist - 1

  let i antalfollowers
  repeat antalfollowers [
    ask item i mylist [


    if verbose? [
        ;;print (word " asking item " i " on mylist to move to item " (i - 1) )
        let mover  [label] of item i mylist
        let moveto [label] of item (i - 1) mylist

        let mover-color  [color] of item i mylist
        let moveto-color [color] of item (i - 1) mylist

        ;; BLUE one moves TO the YELLOW ONE at the end of this second
        print (word " move " mover " to " moveto )
        ask item i mylist [set color blue set shape "square" set size 2]
        ask item (i - 1)  mylist [set color yellow set shape "square" set size 2]
        display
        wait 4
        ask item i mylist [set color mover-color set shape "circle" set size 1]
        ask item (i - 1)  mylist [set color moveto-color set shape "circle" set size 1]
        display

      ]

      move-to (item (i - 1) mylist)


        ;;print word "just moved follower " i  ;;//////////////////////////
      ;; wait 0.1 ;;////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ]
    set i i - 1
  ]

   ask first mylist [
    right random-float wigglefactor
    left random-float wigglefactor
    fd 1
  ]

end

to-report makechain
  let mylist []
  let text "MGIVEQCCTSICSRYQ"   ;; NOTE - this has a repeat of CC in it which SOMETIMES gets tied (23456 tick 2)
  let startx random-xcor / -3
  let starty random-ycor / -3

  let i 0
  repeat length text [
    create-cells 1 [
      set color green
      set shape "circle"
      set label item i text
      set paired? false
      set mylist lput self mylist
      setxy startx + i * .75 starty + i * .75
    ]
    set i i + 1
  ]

  report mylist
end

to clear-stop                   ;;////////////////////////////////
  set stop-requested? FALSE     ;;////////////////////////////////
end                             ;;////////////////////////////////
```

> Anyway, here's how to run it to reproduce the problem and examine it
>   in fine detail very closely.
>
> ### WHAT IS IT?
>
> model of DNA in motion modified for troubleshooting.  When a "C" cell
>   touches another "C" cell in step 746, and sets a link between the two
>   C cells and ties them to move as one,   the algorithm for motion
>   breaks somehow.   This may help figure out why,
>
> ### HOW IT WORKS
>
> This has added to it a msec-per-tick slider, default 50, to set the
>   display speed about right if you leave the usual speed slider at the
>   very top in the middle (normal).
>
> I also added a button ("clear stop") and a switch ( verbose?)
>   normally off.  With verbose? ON,  the model runs very very slowly and
>   color codes which cell is about to move to which cell ( blue is moving
>   to yellow ) and they both temporarily change to squares.
>
> ### HOW TO USE IT
>
> 1) set msecs-per-tick to 50 2) shut off verbose?, click SETUP, click
>   GO.  The model will run 746 ticks. ( thats with the random-seed set to
>   a value of 34567 in globals. )
>
> 3) After it stops at tick 746.   click clear-stop.
>
> NOTICE the CTI group at the upper right. This is logically BETWEEN the
>   two C-cells which have linked up. This group will be snipped-out of
>   the moving DNA  It has who numbers  7, 8, 9 and 10 as you can see by
>   inspecting it.
>
> 4) click one-step 6 times to advance to where you can see more clearly
>   that the two groups have become separate.  Then turn on verbose? and
>   click one-step once to watch the gory details with a 4 second pause
>   between cell-moves and the running commentary in the Command Center
>   telling which cells are about to move.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Wade. I'm looking into you code. But also considering an alternative design. Instead of having the string designed as a chain of followers, I'm wondering whether the string could be designed as linked cells, where a) the cells wiggle a bit individually, and b) the overall string floats around. I haven't been able to do this yet.